# Is there a similar way towrite an EF query to sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2016

my SQL Query:

```sql
SELECT 
   (SELECT MAX(LastModifiedDate)
      FROM (VALUES (CreatedDate),(SubmittedDate),(ApprovedDate),(CATStaffApprovedDate)) AS UpdateDate(LastModifiedDate)) 
   AS LastModifiedDate
FROM contractinvoiceperday
```

Is there a similar way to get the same result using Entity framework of C#?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **LINQ** syntax to write **SQL** query with Entity framework. Your code will look like this:

```
var lastModifiedDate = dbContext.ContractInvoicePerDay
    .Select(c => new
    {
        LastModifiedDate = new[]
        {
            c.CreatedDate,
            c.SubmittedDate,
            c.ApprovedDate,
            c.CATStaffApprovedDate
        }.Max()
    })
    .FirstOrDefault()
    ?.LastModifiedDate;
```

You can learn more about **LINQ** [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)